# java command line execution giving error when a jar path is included in cmd

Tags: java, command-line, jar

When we have a java file(Mainclassfile) which has dependency from a jar. Then we generally use below commands to compile and execute it.

javac -cp jar_path.jar Mainclassfile.java

java -cp jar_path.jar Mainclassfile

But for me compile command is working but execute command is throwing below error.

**Error: Could not find or load main class Mainclassfile
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Mainclassfile**

I tried java -cp .;jar_path.jar Mainclassfile since i am using windows but still same error.

Note: there is only one class in that file and its name is the file names as well.

Comment: You have a declaration `public class Mainclassfile {...}` *which is an application*? (bad name btw) Does it have a `package` declaration?

Comment: check if there is a `Mainclassfile.class` in the actual directory (and you need `.` in the classpath as in `java -cp .;jar_path.jar Mainclassfile`)

Comment: @user85421 There is Mainclassfile.class in the directory. There is a . in the mentioned command, check again.

Comment: @g00se i know its bad name but it should work. Ithe file doesnt have any package declaration

Comment: sorry for trying to help - I cannot see what is in the directory, so better to ask since not given in the question. I just wanted to confirm that `.` is needed; you did not use it in the two first commands, and as you wrote, it looks like you are not sure that it is indeed needed!

Comment: and, by the way, maybe you should "check again" the question... and the class name...  actually posting the class declaration would have been helpful (no guessing needed like now)

Comment: What concerns me is that your declared code keeps changing. You used to have a dot in the class path and it's now gone. It should be as @user85421 has said

Comment: (probably incomplete) checklist: 1) no `package` statement (for this question;) 2) class name **exactly** `Mainclassfile` - Java is case-sensitive; 3) created class file name exactly `Mainclassfile.class` - even if Window is NOT case-sensitive; 4) actual class file `Mainclassfile.class` found in one of the folders or in one of the JARs on the CLASSPATH (`-cp` option) - not in some sub-folders of these - `.` representing the actual working directory (as in last command posted in the question;) [ 5) only one `Mainclassfile.class` found on the CLASSPATH - to avoid confusion about which is taken ]